# C# Group blocks beetwen divs

Tags: c#, .net

I getting source code from some website.

Code is like this:

```
<div class="block">
 <div class="blocktext">Bla</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
 <div class="blocktext">Bla</div>
</div>
```

How to group blocks and view text from blocktext?

Example:

```
var blocks[] = list all "div block";
blocks[1] = HERE IS TEXT from blocktext
```

Thanks. I need to make a program that downloads the ads from the pages

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking

Comment: Have a look Html Agility Pack at http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/273/using-the-htmlagilitypack-to-parse-html-in-asp-net

Comment: I have get strings from string.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx
and then, when you're mastering C#, this: https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/